# How to skip the first element that has the same class name and also have a "Greater-than" condition

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I want to select a button which contains a number greater than 1, so i have written the following:

```
//*mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2][number(.) > 1]
```

My issue is that i want to avoid the first element, because it is irrelevant,  my solution was that i tried putting index [1] at the end:

```
 //*mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2][number(.) > 1][1]
```

but all it did was that it decreased found elements to 0,  any ideas ?

PC:  I also tried putting and between the two conditions and it didn't do anything at all

Comment: How about below xpath: `(//*mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2][number(.) > 1])[position()>1]` . It will return all elements except first one

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first element, you can use `position()` index. In your case :

```
//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[number(.)>1][position()>1]
```

or

```
//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[number(.)>1][not(position()=1)]
```

Note that the following expression should work without the `number()` function :

```
//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[.>1][position()>1]
```

Side note : you can use `()` to select the first element of the page which fulfill your conditions :

```
 (//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[.>1])[1]
```

EDIT : 3 options to test :

```
//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div[position()>1]/div[2]/text()[.>1]
(//*/sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[.>1])[position()>1]
//div[@class="sb-event-list__selection sb-event-list__selection--european"][position()>1]/div[contains(@class,"sb-event-list__selection__outcome-value")][.>1]
```

Comment: Sorry, Xpath that i showcased is changed, but i used the method that u proposed 

(//* /sb-mobile-odds/div//sb-mobile-list-outcome[1]/div/div[2]/text()[number(.)>1])[1]


it only showed one element, i want it to show all elements except the first one


PC: the first value that i'm trying to get rid of is an integer , although other elements that i'm aiming to select some of them are integers aswell, dunno if its helpful

Comment: -_-. Post has been edited. Should be OK now. I thought you wanted to keep only the first  appearing element. Sorry for the confusion. If this doesn't work, please post relevant HTML code.

Comment: This is just one div container for one of the elements:     



`<div _ngcontent-uuy-c94="" class="sb-event-list__selection sb-event-list__selection--european" pt="" pt-item="odd"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-uuy-c94="" class="sb-event-list__selection__outcome-name ng-star-inserted" pt="" pt-item="outcome"> 1 </div><div _ngcontent-uuy-c94="" class="sb-event-list__selection__outcome-value font-ka font-extraBold ng-star-inserted" font="" pt="" pt-item="odd"><!----><!----> 2.55 </div></div>`

Comment: Post has been edited with 3 options to test. The position of the position predicate (`[position()>1]`) is important. And also hard to determine without seeing the full HTML code.;|